# lotus.domino.local.Item cannot be cast to lotus.domino.RichTextItem

Tags: xpages, richtext

I try to put a file into a richtext but it crashes !
In my first code, I try to use directly "getFirstItem", in first time it was ok but now i try to use it again and it crashed. 
In second time i pass with an object and it find my obj doesn't an richtextItem (instanceof) ???

I don't understand.
I have the message : "lotus.domino.local.Item cannot be cast to lotus.domino.RichTextItem" ?
Could you help me ?

```
public void copieFichierDansRichText(String idDocument, String nomRti, File file,
        String nameFichier, String chemin) throws NotesException {

    lotus.domino.Session session = Utils.getSession();
    lotus.domino.Database db = session.getCurrentDatabase();
    lotus.domino.Document monDoc = db.getDocumentByUNID(idDocument);
    lotus.domino.RichTextItem rtiNew = null;
    try {
        try {
            if (monDoc != null) {
                // if (monDoc.getFirstItem(nomRti) != null) {
                // rtiNew = (lotus.domino.RichTextItem)
                // monDoc.getFirstItem(nomRti);
                // } else {
                // rtiNew = (lotus.domino.RichTextItem)
                // monDoc.createRichTextItem(nomRti);
                // }

                Object obj = null;
                if (monDoc.getFirstItem(nomRti) != null) {
                    obj = monDoc.getFirstItem(nomRti);
                    if (obj instanceof lotus.domino.RichTextItem) {
                        rtiNew = (lotus.domino.RichTextItem) obj;
                    } 
                } else {
                    obj = monDoc.createRichTextItem(nomRti);
                    if (obj instanceof lotus.domino.RichTextItem) {
                        rtiNew = (lotus.domino.RichTextItem) obj;
                    }
                }

                PieceJointe pieceJointe = new PieceJointe();
                pieceJointe = buildPieceJointe(file, nameFichier, chemin);

                rtiNew.embedObject(EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", pieceJointe.getChemin()
                        + pieceJointe.getNomPiece(), pieceJointe.getNomPiece());
                monDoc.computeWithForm(true, false);
                monDoc.save(true);
            }
        } finally {
            rtiNew.recycle();
            monDoc.recycle();
            db.recycle();
            session.recycle();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

EDIT : I try to modify my code with yours advices but the items never considerate as richtextitem. It is my problem. I don't understand why, because in my field it is a richtext ! For it, the item can't do :

```
rtiNew = (lotus.domino.RichTextItem) item1;
```

because item1 not be a richtext !!!
I was trying to take all the fields and pass in the item one by one, and it never go to the obj instance of lotus.domini.RichTextItem....

```
Vector items = doc.getItems();
for (int i=0; i<items.size(); i++) {
   // get next element from the Vector (returns java.lang.Object)
   Object obj = items.elementAt(i);

   // is the item a RichTextItem?
   if (obj instanceof RichTextItem) {
      // yes it is - cast it as such // it never go here !!
      rt = (RichTextItem)obj;
   } else {
      // nope - cast it as an Item
      item = (Item)obj;
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this run within the XPages context? I don't recognize the `Utils.getSession()` call

Comment: try to handle it: http://lekkimworld.com/2006/04/13/java_in_notes_domino_explained_casting_101.html

Comment: The session : public static Object getVariableResolver(String nomVariable) {
  FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  return ctx.getApplication().getVariableResolver().resolveVariable(ctx, nomVariable);
 }

 
 public static Session getSession() {
  return (Session) getVariableResolver("session");
 }

Comment: OK, you can have a look at the answer I posted. There's a shortcut method for that and that I used in the example: `DominoUtils.getCurrentSession()`

Comment: What is a "lotus.domino.local.item" ? it's different than "lotus.domino.item" ? Why ?

Comment: It shouldn't matter to you. `lotus.domino.Item` is the interface you should always refer to - it's good rule for the whole Java language world actually. `lotus.domino.local.Item` is the actual interface class implementation used behind the scenes (in this case for code executed on the local server and not through remote calling).

Comment: with your modification, this is the exception i catch : java.lang.ClassCastException: lotus.domino.local.Item incompatible with lotus.domino.RichTextItem

Comment: Make sure you never import any `lotus.domino.local.*` classes, just `lotus.domino.*` classes. If you do, delete the import declarations and use CTRL + SHIFT + O to organize the import and, once again, carefully choose any non local class.

Comment: i try to do the same thing with document OpenNtf, it's the same message, with lotus.domino.local but i have no lotus.domino.local !!! :O I'm pulling my hair out !!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. First of all I would set up a util class method to handle the object recycling in a neater way:

```
public enum DominoUtil {
    ;

    public static void recycle(Base... bases) {
        for (Base base : bases) {
            if (base != null) {
                try {
                    base.recycle();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Do nothing
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly I would remove the reduntants try/catch blocks and simplify it like this:

```
private void copieFichierDansRichText(String idDocument, String nomRti, File file,
    String nameFichier, String chemin) {

  Session session = DominoUtils.getCurrentSession();
  Database db = session.getCurrentDatabase();
  Document monDoc = null;

  try {
    monDoc = db.getDocumentByUNID(idDocument);

    Item item = monDoc.getFirstItem(nomRti);

    if (item == null) {
      item = monDoc.createRichTextItem(nomRti);
    } else if (item.getType() != Item.RICHTEXT) {
      // The item is not a rich text item
      // What are you going to do now?
    }

    RichTextItem rtItem = (RichTextItem) item;

    PieceJointe pieceJointe = new PieceJointe();
    pieceJointe = buildPieceJointe(file, nameFichier, chemin);

    rtItem.embedObject(EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", pieceJointe.getChemin()
        + pieceJointe.getNomPiece(), pieceJointe.getNomPiece());

    monDoc.computeWithForm(true, false);
    monDoc.save(true);
  } catch (NotesException e) {
    throw new FacesException(e);
  } finally {
    DominoUtil.recycle(monDoc);
  }
}
```

Finally, apart from the monDoc, you need not recycle anything else. Actually `Session` would be automatically recycled and anything beneath with it (so no need to recycle db, let alone the session!, good rule is don't recycle what you didn't instantiate), but it's not bad to keep the habit of keeping an eye on what you instantiate. If it were a loop with many documents you definitively want to do that. If you also worked with many items you would want to recycle them as early as possible. Anyway, considered the scope of the code it's sufficient like this. Obviously you would call `DominoUtil.recycle` directly from the try block. If you have multiple objects you can recycle them at once possibly by listing them in the reverse order you set them (eg. `DominoUtil.recycle(item, doc, view)`).

Also, what I think you miss is the check on the item in case it's not a `RichTextItem` - and therefore can't be cast. I put a comment where I think you should decide what to do before proceeding. If you let it like that and let the code proceed you will have the code throw an error. Always better to catch the lower level exception and re-throw a higher one (you don't want the end user to know more than it is necessary to know). In this case I went for the simplest thing: wrapped `NotesException` in a `FacesException`.

Comment: i never send a field which not a richtext on parameter

Comment: If you are confident then just delete the `else` block or leave it. It won't change the outcome